# Group by Week number starting monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Group by Week number starting monday

CREATE TABLE weekdays
(
    StartDate datetime NOT NULL
  , CountValue INT      NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO weekdays (StartDate , CountValue ) VALUES
  ('2015-04-01', 4),
  ('2015-04-02', 1),
  ('2015-04-07', 2),
  ('2015-04-08', 8),
  ('2015-04-09', 3),
  ('2015-04-15', 2),
  ('2015-04-16', 6);

SELECT      DATEPART(wk, StartDate )     weekno
        ,   SUM(CountValue )           totalvalue
FROM        weekdays
GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, StartDate )

Monday week 14 - April 4 2015 - April 10 2015

will be comparing totals for 2015 & 2016

Comment: SQL Server defaults to Sunday-Saturday weeks when configured in English (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  So for 2, April 10th is week 16, April 3rd through April 9th is week 15.

Comment: I don't really like using datepart for weeks. I prefer a datediff in weeks from a startdate (where the startdate day is whatever day I need it to be).

Answer (score 1):

i may be wrong in your desired solution

have you exclude the day falling on weekend or you want include it all 7 days

have you considered ISO_week instead of week in both query

please go through bellowed blog it may give you and idea as it is not that much complicated if you use datediff function

http://dotnetblue.blogspot.in/2013/10/calculate-difference-between-two-dates.html

Comment: sorry week should start on monday i.e need total for Monday week 14 - April 4 2015 - April 10 2015